# AR.js not recognizing markers when used with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aframe, ar.js

I'm using A-frame with AR.js, in my project I need dynamic html so I also use vue.js.
I have a working code that display text on a hiro marker, but whenever I add `<div id=app>` for vue.js, the camera can't seem to find the marker and there is no error messages in the console.

here is the simplest way to reproduce the bug.

```
  <body>
        <div id="app">
          <a-scene>
            <a-marker preset="hiro">
              <a-entity>
                      //text
              </a-entity>
            </a-marker>
          </a-scene>
        </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I don't think Vue and A-frame are compatible like that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Vue and A-frame don't always play well together. The "quick and dirty" solution here could be to build your AR.js and use Vue with an iframe.